# Switch navigator in React Native version 0.62.2

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i am using react-native version 0.62.2
in main screen, i dont want to back to Login screen by back button
in older react-native version, the createSwitchNavigator help me solve it
but react native version 0.62.2 can not use createSwitchNavigator
anyone can help me, help me!!!!

```
          <NavigationContainer
            ref={containerRef}
            initialState={initialNavigationState}>
            <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="LoginScreen">
              <Stack.Screen
                name="LoginScreen"
                component={LoginScreen}
              />
              <Stack.Screen
                name="MainScreen"
                component={MainScreen}
              />
            </Stack.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the issue with `react-native` version!
This issue seems to be with the `react-navigation` version.
The code snippet you've posted is an example of v5 of `react-navigation`. If you prefer to use `createSwitchNavigator()`, then install `react-navigation` v4 and you'll be good to go!

Official Docs for `react-navigation` v4 :  https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/getting-started/